# Unanswerable "Allow access to phone data" prompt that comes up once per second

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-9, android-auto

When I plug my Samsung Galaxy S9 phone into the Renault Zoe car, I get a flood of prompts about whether or not I want to allow access to the phone data. Cannot tell how many times I allowed that in the past, but my phone seems to forget it.

Now, that behavior has changed a bit because the prompt disappears before I am able to click it. It also comes back the next second and the next and the next. The error is new and I have had my car in over a year without problems.

Can I get rid of the prompt? Is there a way to make the phone understand that I want to give access to the car once and for all?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you car tries to access the phone using MTP protocol (the standard file exchange protocol also used by Windows and the other OS if you connect a phone via USB).

If you get multiple prompts this means your car is connecting multiple times (or tries to) or the USB connection is unstable (defect cable?).

If it is just the car trying to access the phone data again and again then you may be able to bypass the prompts by enabling USB phone data access by default.

You can enabled MTP by default in Developer Options menu (hidden by default can be enabled usually by tapping build number in phone info four times).

Search in the developer menu for `USB configuration` and change it to `MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)` or a similar named item that belongs to the MTP/data mode.

Comment: How do I enable USB phone data access by default? When I click "Default USB Configuration" in developer options, I can select something from: Transferring files /Android Auto (selected), USB tethering, MIDI, Transferring Images, Charging phone only. Maybe I could try uninstall android auto?

Comment: @AndersLindén The option `Transferring files / Android Auto` should be the correct one. Also make sure the phone is not locked (lockscreen) when you connect it to your car.

Comment: It is not locked, so the solution would not change anything.

Comment: @AndersLindén Then this is something Samsung specific. You can try to Force Stop the system app "USBSettings". For some users this fixed the permanent USB nag screen.

Comment: Restarting did not help